# Login and Sign up button again showing when page is refreshed or pressed cntrl+shift+R after "logged In" in angular and spring

Tags: javascript, spring, angular, angular6

Actually I have login.component.html and i enter the username and password from then and from where the login method is checked calling the login.component.ts class and if it successful it is either navigated to userdashboard or admindashboard. Then the "Login" and "Signup" button disappers.But refreshing the page then the login and singup button is still shown though it is logged in.

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { UserService } from '../user.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { LoginAuthService } from '../login-auth.service';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

      notLoggedIn:boolean;
        public user:any={};

      constructor(private userService:UserService,private router:Router,public authService:LoginAuthService) { 
          this.authService.isLoggedIn();
      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

       loginUser(user:any){
        this.userService.loginUser(user).subscribe((response) => {

            if(response){
            if(response.token){
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser',JSON.stringify(response));
                    if(response.user.role==='ADMIN'){
                        this.router.navigate(['/admindashboard']);
                    }else{
                        this.router.navigate(['/userdashboard']);
                    }
                }
                } 
            },error => {

          this.notLoggedIn=true;
                console.log(error);

            })

      }
    }
```

I have app.component.ts where it checks the currentstatus whether the user is logged in or not.

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginAuthService } from './login-auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'PCA';
  public currentstatus: any;

  constructor(private authService:LoginAuthService,private router:Router){

  }

  ngOnInit() {

     this.currentstatus=this.authService.getStatus().
       subscribe(currentstatus => {
         this.currentstatus=currentstatus;
       })
  }

  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }

}
```

login-auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import  { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import  { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginAuthService {

    private subject=new Subject<any>();

    isLoggedIn(){
       if(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')){
        this.subject.next({status: true});
       }
       else{
            this.subject.next({status: false});
       }
    }

    clearStatus(){
    this.subject.next();
  }

  getStatus(): Observable<any>{
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
  constructor() { }
}
```

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router:Router){

}

canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state:RouterStateSnapshot){
    if(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')){
        return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
}


}
```

app-routing.module.ts where I have activated AuthGuard

```
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';

 const routes: Routes = [   { path: 'userdashboard', component: UserdashboardComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
         { path: 'admindashboard', component: AdmindashboardComponent ,canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
          { path: 'myprofile', component: MyprofileComponent ,canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
          { path: 'manageuser', component: ManageUserComponent ,canActivate:[AuthGuard] }
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      <li> <a routerLink="home"  routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="signup" routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="!currentstatus.status">Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="login"  routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="!currentstatus.status">Login</a></li>
       <li><a (click)="logout()" *ngIf="currentstatus.status">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The items in navbar are shown according to the currentstatus.status. It's value is either true or false.

The successful login page opens like this with currentstatus.status=true.

[image]

but after instantly i refresh the page or press cntrl+shift+r.Login and signup button is showing again and the content after login is also showing.

[image]

I have used the JWT authentication token method and login method is checked using api which return user if everything is correct:

```
@PostMapping(value="/login")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> login(@RequestBody User user,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        try {
            Authentication authentication= authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()));
            final JwtUser userDetails=(JwtUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
            System.out.println(userDetails.getAuthorities());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            final String token=jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
            response.setHeader("Token",token);
            return new ResponseEntity<UserDTO>(new UserDTO(userDetails.getUser(), token),HttpStatus.OK);
            }catch(Exception e) {
            throw new UnauthorizedExcpetion(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient , HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

    this.http=http;
   }

   saveUser(user:any):Observable<any>{
         const headers=new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});
         return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/registration",user,{headers:headers});
   }

   loginUser(user:any):Observable<any>{
         const headers=new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});
         return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/login",user,{headers:headers});
   } 

   getAllUsers(token: any):Observable<any>{
         const headers=new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':'Bearer '+token});
         return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/users",{headers:headers});
   }   

    getUser(token: any):Observable<any>{
         const headers=new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':'Bearer '+token});
         return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/getuser",{headers:headers});
   } 


    deleteUser(user:any):Observable<any>{
         const headers=new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'});
         return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/deleteUser",user,{headers:headers});
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem resides into reinitialization of the app when you refresh the page. I can't be sure bucause you haven't posted your `UserService`, but I think you are not reloading from `localStorage` your jwt token when you initialize your app.

This could be a good approach to solve your problem:

1. load/reload angular app
2. services are instantiated
3. during `LoginAuthService` or `UserService` initialization try to access `localStorage`'s saved jwt token
4. during component initialization subscribe to `LoginAuthService.getStatus()`

If it doesn't work try to put some `console.log()` to check if you have sync problems, keeping in mind that subscribtion to `subject` must be done before `next()` is called on the `subject`

So you could need one point more

5. request `LoginAuthService` or `UserService` to renew the subject value

Comment: It is not relevant, sorry. Let me know if you tried something new based on my answer and what is the result, pleaee